# Ajax call theme functions from front

Tags: functions, ajax

Here's what I try to do : calling a function in my theme functions.php from the front of my theme.

So, on the front :

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-vote',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var $that = jQuery(this);
                var id = $that.attr('data-id');
                var data = {
                    'action': 'voteIncrementer',
                    'id': id
                };
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data,function(response){ // ajaxurl is defined in footer.php > var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
                    console.log(response);
                    $that.find('.vote-count').html(response);


                });
            });
```

And the related function in functions.php :

```
add_action("wp_ajax_voteIncrement", "voteIncrement");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_voteIncrement", "voteIncrement");

function voteIncrement(){

    echo 'hello';
    die();
}
```

Quit simple right ? But the thing is : in my JS, the log returns 0 (that means that wp-ajax can't find my function).

What I am missing ?

Comment: Sorry for that, that's just a f***g wrong function name : voteIncrement / voteIncrementer. :/

Comment: I know that frustrating feeling, happens to all of us though :)

Comment: Yes, that happens to all of us from time to time. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think that your problem is `ajaxurl` is not available for your script. Try to defined that varibale before your js code is loaded. The best way is using wp_localize_script:

The PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_scripts' );
function cyb_enqueue_scripts() {
    //Change the key and url with yours
    wp_register_script('my-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/my-js.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-js');

    //Localize script data to be used in my-js.js
    $scriptData = array();
    $scriptData['ajaxurl'] = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    $scriptData['action'] = 'voteIncrement';

    wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'my_js_data', $scriptData );

}


add_action("wp_ajax_voteIncrement", "voteIncrement");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_voteIncrement", "voteIncrement");

function voteIncrement(){

    echo 'hello';
    die();
}
```

The js:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn-vote').on('click',function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var $that = jQuery(this);
            var id = $that.attr('data-id');
            var data = {
                'action': my_js_data.action,
                'id': id
            };

            jQuery.post( my_js_data.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $that.find('.vote-count').html(response);
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, I would change the post method in the ajax request for get. It is faster than post and your case seems not to need a post request.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but actually, I was calling voteIncrementer when I mean voteIncrement... Sorry for that :)